# Entity Framework with existing classes

Tags: entity-framework

I have searched every way I can think of for the answer to this, so forgive me if I have overlooked a post...

I have a project containing model classes that I want to remain database-ignorant (pretend someone handed me the code and said "you're not allowed to modify one character of these classes"). I want to persist these to SQL Server using Entity Framework. So far, I have been able to use the fluent API to map anything that EF couldn't determine logically. But I have hit a block with the following:

```
public class PhotoPost {
    // mapped as Key with fluent API - comes from blog provider
    public string PostID { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public Collection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}

public class Photo {
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public Image LoadImage() { … }
}
```

I have a class, PhotoPost, which represents a type of Post on a Blog. The PhotoPost instance has a collection of objects of type Photo, all of which need to be persisted to the database. My problem is that the Photo doesn't really have a primary key. Blog provider doesn't guarantee the Url will not change, and I can't touch this code to add an arbitrary ID. Furthermore, I don't really *want* an ID. The code that is going to interact with these objects shouldn't/won't know whether these objects came from the blog's API or from a local database (or XML, ...), so I don't really want to clutter up my code with boilerplate in subclassing these objects in another project just to add IDs everywhere (and constructors to create subclasses with IDs from parent classes without, as above) to make EF happy.

Is subclassing to add IDs my only option, or is there a way that I can meet in the middle, between "entity" and "complex type"? (From what I understand, complex types must be one-to-one with their parent entities.)

Comment: How do you expect this to look in the DB? this will help you set up your model. Perhaps draw out your table structure and we will have some better advice on how to achieve it in EF

Comment: I would have a Photos table that would have an auto-incrementing PK (which I would not care about) and a FK to the PhotoPosts table. Updates to Photos are not possible, and deletes can only occur if the parent Post is deleted. So, I don't even want to see or think about the ID in code. Is there a way to do this, or an easy way to subclass those XYZPosts that have issues like this one in order to use them with EF?